# Trying to arrange email addresses from DB

Tags: php, email

Pulling my hair out on this one, which I am sure is simple for someone who knows php... I am trying to grab email addresses that have their email option set to 'yes'.  The echo in the scipt below returns all the correct email addresses, but I need them represented in $show_users so it can be used in the "TO" line of the email script, I just can't seem to get all the email addresses in the $show_user variable, it returns the last email in the query, where I need all 3 in this example.  Hopefully someone can help since I am a newbie at this code, thanks very much.

```
echo $user['user_email']; 

$users = $phpcdb->get_get_users_emails($phpc_uid);  \\db script

foreach ($users as $user) {
$show_users = var_export($user['user_email'], true); 
     }
return tag('h2', _($show_users));
```

OUTPUT from "echo"
  email1.comemail2.comemail3.com
OUTPUT from Sshow_user
  'email3.com'

Comment: first thing you'll have to do is explain exactly how this get_get_users_emails() method works. we're not psychic. Then look at your foreach loop, and look at what it's doing: overwriting `$show_users` with EVERY user you've fetch, leaving you only with the last one.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$show_users` should be an array and built like this:

```
$show_users = array();
foreach ($users as $user) {
    $show_users[] = $user['user_email'];
}
```

Later you can turn it back into a string using `join()`:

```
join(',', $show_users); // "a@b.com,c@d.com"
```